# how to plot a route between source to destination with respect to GMSMarker or annotation in iOS Google Map sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, routes

With the help of this tutorial link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdV7bCWuDYg&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKkdC4GCZp3JGrY4ctWHnHo&index=10

I am able to draw a route between Source (New York) to Destination (Washington) but here is it possible to draw route with respect to GMSMarker for example drawing route between New York to Washington via lakewood and vineland or were ever user drop a pin

platform - iOS 
,SDK - Google Map
,language - Objective -C

i searched but cannot find....
Thank you in advance.....

Comment: If you're talking about setting a waypoint in between your start and destination, then [this](http://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial/) tutorial may be useful to you.

Comment: thank you...but if u have any source for objective-C it would be great...!!